# Giving command line arguments to java program over git-bash

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, git-bash

I'm currently working on a program to zip and unzip files/directories and it behaves kind of weird when I call it over the git bash.

The program takes three arguments (zip/unzip, inputPath, outputPath).
For Example:

```
java -jar zip_unzip.jar --zip H:\\zip_test  H:\\test5\zip_test_4.zip
```

Everything works fine when I call it over Eclipse or CMD. It creates the directory structure if it doesn't already exist and zips the input Folder into the newly created output folder. But when I call it over the git bash like in the example above it somehow "ignores" the backslash and instead of creating a folder called `test5\`, creates a zip-archive called `test5zip_test_4.zip`

Here's a snippet of the code that takes care of creating the directory structure, where zippedFolder is the outputPath-Parameter:

```
File directoryToZip = new File(inputFolder);
String targetZippedFolder = zippedFolder;
targetZippedFolder = targetZippedFolder.replace("\\", "/");
//create directory to store archive in, if it doesn't already exist
File destDir = new File(targetZippedFolder.substring(0, targetZippedFolder.lastIndexOf("/")));
if (!destDir.exists()) {
    destDir.mkdirs();
}
```

In line 3 of the codesnippet I'm replacing every backslash with a forwardslash because I thought this would make it platform-independent.

Can someone explain the behavior of the git bash to me and maybe suggest a more platform-independent path handling method?

Comment: Is it a typo that there is only a single slash in ` H:\\test5\zip_test_4.zip` ?  Git Bash could be treating it as an escape. If I have `$ cat C:\\Users\\Philip\trim.sed` I get a file not found error. But with `$ cat C:\\Users\\Philip\\trim.sed` it works.

Comment: No it's not. I just tried to make it compatible to every path format the user inputs. When I enter it like this in Windows CMD it works perfectly. But I the escape explains it.

Comment: Yes, for me too in CMD. I was showing what happens with Git Bash. Maybe you should always use forward slash.